# Applying reduce method on groupingby result in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, mapreduce

m new to java and trying [Java 8 map and reduce](https://www.sitepoint.com/java-8-streams-filter-map-reduce/).I have current scenario.

I have a class named DS which is as following:

```
package com.srm;

public class DS {
  private String time;
  private int transaction;
  private String item;
    public DS(String time, int transaction, String item) {
      this.time = time;
      this.transaction = transaction;
      this.item = item;
    }
 //Simple getters and setter here.
}
```

There are multiple items with multiple number of transaction.

```
 Map<String, List<DS>> myStream = mylist.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DS::getItem));
```

here **mylist** contains records of items with number of transaction and time of transaction.and this line grouped these record as

```
  {Cherry me Dried fruit=[com.srm.DS@7699a589//(no. of transactions), com.srm.DS@58372a00, com.srm.DS@4dd8dc3], Brownie=[com.srm.DS@6d03e736]}
```

Now i want to add transactions of each item and convert upper response to this:

```
 {Cherry me Dried fruit=10, Brownie=1}
```

I have used map and reduce like following code:

```
Iterator<String> itr = myStream.keySet().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if (itr.next() != null) {
                List<DS> values = myStream.get(itr.next());
                Stream<Integer> lengthStream = values.stream().map(s -> s.getTransaction());
            int sum = lengthStream.reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y);
            }
        }
```

which is not a good aproach.i can't use .map() and .reduce() one liner for this.Is it possible to do this without a loop over object keys?

Any help please!

Comment: where are you even using the `sum` variable? its reassigned whenever a key is iterated..

Comment: just doing system.out.println() as jst need to show .map and .reduce() methods' functionality.

Comment: probably you can rewrite it as `Map<String, List<DS>> myStream = mylist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DS::getItem));
        myStream.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(v.stream().map(DS::getTransaction).reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y)));`

Comment: @nullpointer thanx for this.You really understood my question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for this:

```
 myList.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
           DS::getItem,
           Collectors.summingInt(DS::getTransaction)
 ))
```

**EDIT:**

```
 myList.stream()
        .map(x -> new SimpleEntry<>(x.getItem(), x.getTransaction()))
        .reduce(
            new HashMap<String, Integer>(),
            (map, entry) -> {
                HashMap<String, Integer> inner = new HashMap<>();
                inner.putAll(map);
                inner.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), Integer::sum);
                return inner;
            },
            (left, right) -> {
                HashMap<String, Integer> inner = new HashMap<>();
                inner.putAll(left);
                inner.putAll(right);
                return inner;
            }
        );
```

Comment: yes i need same result but requirement is using map and reduce.is it possible?

Comment: @N.A "requirement"? map reduce is a generic concept in general... you could do you it I guess like that, but why?

Comment: its a generic concept but i need to show this by .map() and .reduce() methods.

Comment: @N.A and btw this operation "maps" via `DS::getItem` and "reduces" via `Collectors.summingInt(DS::getTransaction)`

Comment: @N.A I think your are confusing yourself right now a bit here and worse you are confusing me here even more, what do you mean via `map`?

Comment: see edited comment please.m talking about methods provieded by java 8.

Comment: [Just want to print the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028027/applying-reduce-method-on-groupingby-result-in-java-8#comment92957494_53028027)...not sure if the question meant `Collect`ing it using the same.

Comment: @N.A can't tell why you would need to use those, but I guess it 's doable; there are multiple ways to do it, one I've updated my answer with, the other is shown by nullpointer in comments - either way, I really doubt this is what you need/want.

Comment: @nullpointer the entire question is un-clear (I voted to close it)

Comment: @Eugene my question is to apply map and reduce concept on a record using java 8 .map() and .reduce().i think i can show the result in console too if i just want to show the working of these 2 methods.i don't know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @N.A sorry but your last phrase added even more confusion now, what console are you talking about at all? I will stop commenting now as this is not going anywhere at this point in time

Comment: sorry for your time waste.i got my answer from @nullpointer above.

Comment: @N.A think about your question now that explicitly says *one liner for this*, your comment here where you say you want `map` and `reduce` and the fact that you say that nullpointer gave you the correct answer, this is beyond me :) if you did get your answer nevertheless, ask him to post it -so you could accept it

Comment: @N.A I believe you are missing an important part, the *concept* behind the operations(`map` and `reduce`) in your case. Also, you've got to understand that sometimes a one-liner cannot be as useful as the iteration(it's not always efficient) you already had. But all of that to just print the sum could have been done in a less complex way I believe.